# Where should you save plugin settings?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins

I am writing an application that has plugins functionality.
Each Plugin will be stored in the **/MyDocuments/AppName/PluginName/** folder.
What is better, saving all plugin settings to the application settings file, or creating separate settings file for each plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For simplicity save everything in one file

**Example**

Here's a basic representation of plugins settings :

```
public class Plugin
{
    public List<PluginSetting> Settings { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PluginSetting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

For simplicity (again) you can use JSON.NET for saving your data :

```
var plugins = new List<Plugin>(new[]
{
    new Plugin
    {
        Name = "plugin1",
        Settings = new List<PluginSetting>(new[]
        {
            new PluginSetting {Name = "volume", Value = 1.0d},
            new PluginSetting {Name = "soundSystemType", Value = "THX"}
        })
    }
});

string serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(plugins, Formatting.Indented);
```

Output of the above example :

```
[
  {
    "Settings": [
      {
        "Name": "volume",
        "Value": 1.0
      },
      {
        "Name": "soundSystemType",
        "Value": "THX"
      }
    ],
    "Name": "plugin1"
  }
]
```

Save this to 'settings.json' for instance.

**NOTE**

You could also use JSON.NET directly against your plugins it will be even simpler, you save their state and restore them as they were, there are attributes such as `[JsonIgnore]` to ignore some settings, i.e. there are probably settings you won't want to save or prefer to restore at some point.

### Where to save your data ?

Take a look at this article :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expect to move a plugin around **with** its settings, I'd say: keep them with the application.

The only consideration might possibly come up, if you use a plugin with **more than one** host applicaton. In that case you must decide if the plugin-applications should share their settings or not.

You might even make it an option of each plugin to have global settings or not..

If keep mine in subkeys of the application's registry key.